# Problema guardar elemento en archivo en C (violacion de segmento)

Tags: c, double, filewriter

tengo un problema que tengo que solucionar en el lenguaje C. La idea es hacer un programa que me permita generar caso de test y un archivo con info al respecto de estos.

A grandes rasgos el problema es el siguiente:

Se requiere generar arreglos de double de una cantidad de elementos N, uno corresponderá a los casos de test de temperatura del aire, otro corresponderá a los casos de test de humedad del aire y una cantidad K (pasada por argumento) corresponderá a K sensores de humedad del suelo (los casos de test de cada sensor van en archivos separados).

Aqui el código

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    double a, aux;
    int tiempoEnSeg, cantSensorHumedadSuelo,auxI;
    FILE *tempAirePointer, *humAirePointer, *humSueloPointer, *infoGeneracionPointer, *verificadorPointer;
    if (argc=3){
        srand(1u); //genera double sin signo
        /* Se debe respetar el orden siguiente de inicializacion:
        (1) sensor de temperatura aire, (2) sensor de humedad aire, (3) sensores de humedad suelo. */

        char idSensorSuelo[42];
        tiempoEnSeg=atoi(argv[1]);
        cantSensorHumedadSuelo=atoi(argv[2]);

        double temperaturaAire[tiempoEnSeg];
        double humedadAire[tiempoEnSeg];
        double humedadSuelo[tiempoEnSeg];
        int verificador[2+cantSensorHumedadSuelo];

        infoGeneracionPointer=fopen("tests/info_generacion.txt","w");

        //Numeros para sensor de temperatura del aire [-40 ... 50]    
        a = 90.0;
        tempAirePointer=fopen("tests/cases/temperatura_aire.dat","wb");
        auxI=0;
        for (int i=0;i<tiempoEnSeg;i++){
            aux=((double)rand()/(double)(RAND_MAX)) * a - 40;
            //guardar el valor generado
            temperaturaAire[i]=aux;
            if (aux >20 && aux <30)
                auxI++;            
        }
        verificador[0]=auxI;
        fprintf(infoGeneracionPointer,"Temperatura del aire\n");
        fprintf(infoGeneracionPointer,"   - Mediciones correctas: %d\n",auxI);
        fprintf(infoGeneracionPointer,"   - Mediciones incorrectas: %d\n\n",tiempoEnSeg-auxI);
        fwrite(temperaturaAire,sizeof(double),tiempoEnSeg,tempAirePointer);
        fclose(tempAirePointer);

        //Numeros para sensor de humedad del aire [0 ... 100]
        humAirePointer=fopen("tests/cases/humedad_aire.dat","wb");
        a = 100.0;
        auxI=0;
        for (int i=0;i<tiempoEnSeg;i++){
            aux=((double)rand()/(double)(RAND_MAX)) * a;
            humedadAire[i]=aux;
            if (aux >75)
                auxI++;
        }
        verificador[1]=auxI;
        fprintf(infoGeneracionPointer,"Humedad del aire\n");
        fprintf(infoGeneracionPointer,"   - Mediciones correctas: %d\n",auxI);
        fprintf(infoGeneracionPointer,"   - Mediciones incorrectas: %d\n\n",tiempoEnSeg-auxI);
        fwrite(humedadAire,sizeof(double),tiempoEnSeg,humAirePointer);
        fclose(humAirePointer);

        //Numeros para sensor de humedad del suelo [0 ... 100]
        a = 100.0;

        for (int j=0;j<cantSensorHumedadSuelo;j++){
            auxI=0;
            for (int i=0;i<tiempoEnSeg;i++){
                aux=((double)rand()/(double)(RAND_MAX)) * a;
                humedadSuelo[i]=aux;
                if (aux >30)
                    auxI++;
                    //guardar el valor generado
                    //
            }
            verificador[2+j]=auxI;
            switch(j){
                case 0 ... 8:
                    snprintf(idSensorSuelo,42,"tests/cases/000%d_humedad_suelo.dat",j+1);
                    break;
                case 9 ... 98:
                    snprintf(idSensorSuelo,42,"tests/cases/00%d_humedad_suelo.dat",j+1);
                    break;
                case 99 ... 998:
                    snprintf(idSensorSuelo,42,"tests/cases/0%d_humedad_suelo.dat",j+1);
                    break;
                default:
                    snprintf(idSensorSuelo,42,"tests/cases/%d_humedad_suelo.dat",j+1);
                    break;            
            }            
            humSueloPointer=fopen(idSensorSuelo,"wb");
            fwrite(humedadSuelo,sizeof(double),tiempoEnSeg,humSueloPointer);
            fclose(humSueloPointer);
            fprintf(infoGeneracionPointer,"Sensor de suelo %d\n",j+1);
            fprintf(infoGeneracionPointer,"   - Mediciones correctas: %d\n",auxI);
            fprintf(infoGeneracionPointer,"   - Mediciones incorrectas: %d\n\n",tiempoEnSeg-auxI);
        }

        fwrite(verificador,sizeof(int),2+tiempoEnSeg,verificadorPointer); //int ocupan 4 bytes
        fclose(infoGeneracionPointer);


    }else{
        printf("El uso de este programa requiere de 2 argumentos para generar\n");
        printf("1. Tiempo expresados en segundos\n");
        printf("2. Cantidad de sensores de humedad del suelo\n");
        }

   return 0;
}
```

El programa requiere de dos argumentos al momentos de su ejecución (además del nombre por supuesto).

El código compila, pero al momento de ejecutarlo me lanza el siguiente mensaje

`Violación de segmento ('core' generado)`,

independientemente del valor de los argumentos pasados por paramentros (incluso su cantidad). Alguna consejo para solucionarlo?

Nota: el programa me genera los archivos, pero no escribe nada en los mismos

Update 1: En un caso me dio, pero despues vuelve a darme el mismo error, es impredecible cuando va o no a saltar

`Violación de segmento ('core' generado)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simplificando el código tenemos:

```
FILE *verificadorPointer;

fwrite(verificador,sizeof(int),2+tiempoEnSeg,verificadorPointer);
```

Y como ves, `verificadorPointer` **no** está inicializado. Ese es el problema.

Comment: Tenes toda la razón! Muchas gracias genio!